# Table-wide constraint in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, database-design, constraints

I'm rather new at Postgres.  Is there any way that I can write a constraint for a table that checks ALL characters fields and tests to make sure that there are no leading or trailing characters IF there is any value in the field?

This way I don't have to itemize each and every character field when I write the constraint.

Thanks!

Comment: A check constraint will do that - but you need one for each column. There is no way to use a wildcard for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot write such a constraint insofar as I am aware.

What you could do is to [create a `DOMAIN`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createdomain.html) that has the check function and then make all of your table columns of that domain type. Assuming that the characters you refer to are spaces:

```
CREATE DOMAIN varchar_no_spaces AS varchar
CHECK ( left(VALUE, 1) <> ' ' AND right(VALUE, 1) <> ' ') );
```

There are many variations on this `CHECK` expression, including regular expression and using different or multiple characters. See the [string functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html) for more options.

Then:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
  f1     varchar_no_spaces,
  ...
);
```

Effectively you relay the constraint check to the level of the domain.